# How can I show and hide input label while focus in and out

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<input class="w3-input" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
<input class="w3-input" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
```

while I click on input I need to hide label in order to get results I created following jquery code but not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".w3-input").click(function(){
    var item_select = this.id; //getting id of clicked item

     $(item_select).focusin(function(){
        $(this).prev("label").hide(); //hide label of clicked item 
    });
      $(item_select).focusout(function(){
        $(this).prev("label").show();
    });
 });

});
```

what's wrong with my code any one help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are registering the `focusin` handler in the `click` handler, when the click happens firs the focusin is triggered then the click, so during the first click there is no `focusin` handler to be triggered. There are other issues also like each click will add more and more handlers.

There is no need for the click event

```js
$(function() {

  $(".w3-input").focus(function() {
    $(this).prev("label").hide(); //hide label of clicked item 
  }).blur(function() {
    $(this).prev("label").show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<input class="w3-input" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
<input class="w3-input" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need the `click`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".w3-input").focusin(function(){
    $("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").hide();
  });
  $(".w3-input").focusout(function(){
    $("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").show();
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kt6xzwtv/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('#'+item_select)`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".w3-input").click(function(){
    var item_select = this.id; //getting id of clicked item
        console.log(item_select)
     $('#'+item_select).focusin(function(e){//add # to target id
        $(this).prev("label").hide(); //hide label of clicked item 
    });
      $('#'+item_select).focusout(function(){//add # to target id
        $(this).prev("label").show();
    });
 });

});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5tnq5ukd/)

You solution is not working if you havent click on input remove the click event works ok

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5tnq5ukd/1/)